# Is there a way to get more characters in SSB 3DS version?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Is there a way to get more characters in SSB 3DS version? Or is it when you get it, you just have those characters. I'm kind of confused, so if you'd answer this question it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Super Smash Bros for 3DS *does* have [unlockable characters](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Unlockable_character#Super_Smash_Bros._for_Nintendo_3DS); 12 of them, in fact.

```
Character         How to unlock                                   Vs. Matches Required
Ness              Clear Classic Mode on any difficulty                              10
Falco             Clear Classic Mode without any continues                          20
Wario             Complete 100-Man Smash                                            30
Lucina            As Marth, clear Classic Mode without any continues                40
Dark Pit          Clear Classic Mode with three or more characters                  50
Dr. Mario         As Mario, clear Classic Mode on intensity 4.0 or higher           60
R.O.B.            Collect at least 200 different trophies                           70
Ganondorf         As Zelda or Link, clear Classic Mode on intensity 5.0 or higher   80
Mr. Game & Watch  Clear Classic Mode with 10 or more characters                     90
Bowser Jr.        As Bowser, clear Classic Mode on intensity 6.0 or higher         100
Duck Hunt Duo     Clear Classic Mode with 8 or more characters                     110
Jigglypuff        Collect at least 30 different equipment items                    120
```

The list is a bit misleading. The "Vs. Matches Required" is only an alternative requirement, so if you want to unlock Ness, you either clear Classic Mode, or you play 10 Vs. Matches.

The Vs. Matches are cummulative. If you've just unlocked Ness by fighting Vs. Matches, you only need to fight 10 more times to challenge Falco. You also don't need to accumulate all these fights in one sitting, so you're free to quit the game or do something else in between.

When the unlock condition is met, the unlockable character will challenge you to a fight. You will fight as the last character you were using. The more characters you have unlocked, the harder the fight will be. If you win, the character will appear in the character selection list, where you can select him/her. If you lose, you'll have to win a match to challenge the character again; luckily, you won't need to meet the unlock conditions again, so make sure you use a character you're comfortable with.